# Iframe jquery behaviours

Tags: jquery, iframe, selection, styling

I'm making a wysiwyg kinda editor with iframe. I want to add a style to the highlighted text. Now I made that kinda word. I say kinda because it behaves a little odd  and is not always exact or it does not get the right word to replace with jquery somehow. 
But roughly. It does work. My first question is why that is.

And my second question is. As you can see in the code the text gets selected when there is a click on the framebody. Then it outputs the selected text into a div which i can see on the page through the features(). This works like a charm. And outputting the selection is no problem at all. Then why is the styling not exact? Like I make a text h2. Not selected text gets the same style too.

And when I change the click to select. So when selecting takes place in the framebody. Do your thing. But that does not work at all. While with click it does work. Trust me when I say, that i'v searched a lot of answers. It could be that I did not read or understood it properly. But it is defenitely making me sweat :). Which I think should be rewarded with a good proper answer. Instead of 20 confusing answers.

```
 $(document).ready(function() 
    {
        var id = createIframe();
        var iFrame = document.getElementById(id);   

        iframebody = $('#'+id).contents().find('body');


        $(iframebody).click(function() 
            {   
                    selectedText = getSelectedText(iFrame);     

                features(iFrame);       
            });
    }); 

    function actions(frame,txt)
    {
    $('#bold').click(function()
    {
        iFrameBody = frame.contentWindow.document.body;

        boldStyle = $(iFrameBody).html().replace(txt, '<b>' + txt + '</b>');

        $(iFrameBody).html(boldStyle);
    }); 

    $('#italic').click(function()
    {
        iFrameBody = frame.contentWindow.document.body;

        italicStyle = $(iFrameBody).html().replace(txt, '<i>' + txt + '</i>');

        $(iFrameBody).html(italicStyle);
    });

    $('#h1').click(function()
    {
        iFrameBody = frame.contentWindow.document.body;

        h1Style = $(iFrameBody).html().replace(txt, '<h1>' + txt + '</h1>');

        $(iFrameBody).html(h1Style);
    });
    }

    function features(frame)
    {
        if(henksFeatures.selectionPreview === true)
        {
            $("#selected-output").text(getSelectedText(iFrame)).show(); 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so instead of using the jquery method replace. I found out execCommand of javascript works impressingly well with the iframe. So no selection problems anymore. SOLVED